# How to safely interface 220VAC in a PCB

Tags: pcb-design, ac, mains

I am making a PCB circuit that detects the state of a mains voltage switch. Now since I am dealing with mains voltage a lot can go wrong and a lot can go wrong badly so I would like to ask for some advice on how to properly deal (and might even use standard practices) with mains voltage on my PCB.

My circuit takes advantage of an unused "throw" pin of the switch, which I can use to detect the voltage. I plan on using an AC input optoisolator (could not find an AC input model for the schematics) to fully isolate my electronics from the mains voltage. There will be several of these detector circuits in a single PCB, the number will range from maybe 5-10 depending on how much I can fit in.

So what I would like advice for are:

- What would be the thinnest trace I can go for the mains voltage, and also the the distance between traces? (1oz copper)
- What would be the best/safest connectors both male and female for this application.
- Is it okay to share the neutral line for all the detectors to reduce the wire connecting to the board?

[image]

Comment: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2729322.pdf

Comment: @jsotola awesome! an opto exactly designed for my usecase. My main concern are the connectors do you have recommendation for those?

Comment: is is unclear to me what you are buiding, so i have no idea what kind of a connector you could use ... you could use almost anything for the low voltage side ... db9, rj45, phono plug, pin header, etc

Comment: @jsotola i am making a switch state detector for residential or small industry, so i the wires used will be the ones used on those area. this project will not really be deployed to the field, but i am building it like to be deployed.

Answer (score 3):

Low consumer quality boards are done like this.

[image]

Since dust and moisture accumulation causes greatly reduced breakdown voltages down from 1kV/mm, it is far better to have an air gap milled in the board between primary and secondary of the Opto.

[image]

*However , your external schematic is nonsense with Line Neutral and switch going to LED.*

Comment: What do you mean by _Line Neutral and switch going to LED_ ? Also is the milling done only in the opto and not also the mains input terminal? You said low consumer quality, how is it done in high quality?

Comment: What do you think L N means?  Milling is done to make an air gap between 3.5kV  creapage rating  primary to secondary under Optos. High quality designs have contamination level specs and safety specs and air gap complies to these ratings.  Consumer spikes can reach 6kV in 1us without filters.  But safety test limits are less.  So high quality design specifies all requirements and may include spike attenuation filter and MOV. with fuse.

Comment: Live and Neutral ? So when the switch is conneceted to the load the opto is "off" and i can interpret that as the switch is "on". When the switch is "off" the circuit is complete for the optocoupler thus turning it "on" i can interpret the signal as the switch is "off"

Comment: I see so they still make the holes that are upto specs. I will try to incorporate as many you have said to the design as possible. Thank you!

Comment: Opto IR diodes are normally current limited 15 mA  using 5V logic 220 ohms or so depending on source Rs

Comment: Considering cost, reconsider Make vs Buy. These interfaces with relays and Optos and cheap logic level drive to AC/DC dry contacts. Don't guess learn from commercial solutions.

Comment: @Jakequin: Tony's lower image shows a good layout with the slots and a very obvious "no-man's land". The upper one (presumably just chosen from an image search) isn't so good. There are no slots, one trace runs right through the line of opto-isolators and another goes under it and so compromises the creepage clearance. I suspect that the upper board is just for isolation or level shifting between DC voltage levels and is not intended for mains applications. See my answer to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/254383/can-you-please-review-my-pcb-design-is-it-safe/254492#254492.

Answer (score 1):

> There will be several of these detector circuit in a single pcb, the
>   number will range from maybe 5-10

This means that you have to route mains voltage from several places to a single detection circuit - **really bad idea!**

It makes more sense to have a tiny PCB that can fit next to each individual switch with low voltage signal going to the common location. It is a) probably will be cheaper, b) easier to install and c) a whole lot safer.

Also, I would not rely on always having SPDT switch available. The optocoupler suggested by @jsotola can be connected in parallel with the load and it will work with SPST switch.

Comment: _But you are NOT using the neutral line in your schematics_ what are you talking about ?? If you are talking about the PCB section of the schematics that is digital ground. I like the idea of breaking it out to smaller pieces, but i have to add special circuits so i can reliably read data over long distances which i still have to look into how

Comment: @Jakequin I am talking about terminal marked "Z" on "external" side of your schematics

Comment: "add special circuits so i can reliably read data over long distances" huh? some network protocols work over _kilometers_ of wiring. You have simple digital level on/off which does not require any special circuits, other than maybe simple TVS

Comment: That is an N just sideways, i do not think there is a z symbol other than impedance i guess

Comment: my bad, I thought you marked ground wire that way. I'll remove that from the answer.