# Design Review Request: AC Mains Monitoring

Tags: circuit-design, pcb-design, mains

I am designing a PCB to monitor 240v RMS mains with a ZMPT101B and YHDC SCT-013-000 current clamps.
I am rectifying with an [LS05-13B05R3](https://www.mornsun-power.com/html/pdf/LS05-13B05R3.html).  I aimed for 32mil clearances and widths with no overlap of opposing nets.

Is there anything on this design that could be improved?  It is my first time delving in a PCB for mains voltages.  I included examples of clearances and measurements in the board layout.  Ignore the LV side of the board with the copper fill, I did not connect PE to anything on the board as it will have a plastic case.  I figure I should not copper fill the HV side either.
Schematic:
[image: Schematic]
Board:
[image: PCB Board]

Comment: IPC-A-610 minimum electrical clearance for AC voltage peaks of 340V is 98.4 mils.

Comment: I would like to see 5 mm or more! A wide no-man's land is, to me, a sign of good design. Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/337632/73158.

Comment: And here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/254492/73158.

Comment: I completely forgot about peak vs rms, thank you.  The good news is my design still has enough clearance for 98.4mils except for the input connector.  I will have to replace that.